# How to use angularjs config block?

Tags: angularjs, ajax, config, angular-config

I am new to angularJS and trying to learn it. I came across config function
where I see two different arguments as in below example.

Example 1

```
dashboardApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
//$urlRouterProvider.when('', '/add');
$stateProvider.state('add', 
                 { 
                     url:'/add?month&year', 
                     templateUrl: 'partial/add.html', 
                     controller: 'AddListController' 
                 })
});
```

Example 2

```
gm.config(['$routeProvider', 'Path', function($routeProvider, Path) {
$routeProvider.when('/login', { 
    templateUrl: Path.view('application/authentication/login.html'), 
    controller: 'authController' 
});
}]);
```

In the first example, config has a function parameter. And in second example config has array parameter.

Can someone please explain to me what is the difference between these two approaches and when to use which?

Comment: Dependency annotation: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#dependency-annotation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS DI annotations - why use them?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24526880/angularjs-di-annotations-why-use-them)

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate, as the poster didn't know what the syntax was, so he/she didn't get as far as asking why to do it.

Answer (score 0):

There are two differences here. The first example is providing configuration for [Angular UI Router](https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/), whereas the second is using ngRoute.

The difference in syntax that you noted is the difference between having code that will not withstand minification (first example) and code that [will withstand minification](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#minification-and-annotation).

Answer (score 0):

+1 to the previous answer pointing out $stateProvider is angular ui-router syntax. I would also point out that declaring $routeProvider has different syntax than other angular items like services and controllers.

Answer (score 0):

You should use ui-route provider as it is better than ngRoute,
ui-router allows you to code your templates in a nested form